# Separate font family from font name node js

Tags: javascript

currently, I'm using fs to read the all available fonts from the folder from disk

```
fs.readdir(fontDirectory, (err, files) => 
{
   // all available fonts
   // 'EncodeSansCondensed-Black.ttf', 'EncodeSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', 'EncodeSansCondensed-ExtraBold.ttf', etc...

});
```

But I'm not sure how to separate the font family from the font name. Can any help on this

Comment: is the font family contained in the filename, or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, it is the file name, probably it will be the list of file names

Comment: Please provide examples of filenames

Comment: consider
eg: [ 'EncodeSansCondensed-Black.ttf',
        'EncodeSansCondensed-Bold.ttf',
        'EncodeSansCondensed-ExtraBold.ttf']

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure the filenames will be of the schema `{fontFamily}-{fontStyle}.ttf` you can use a regex:

```js
const regex = /(.*)-(.*).ttf/gm;
const filename = 'EncodeSansCondensed-Black.ttf';

const match = regex.exec(filename);

const fontFamily = match[1];
const fontStyle = match[2];

console.log(fontFamily, fontStyle);
```

Comment: Regex is a bit overkill, splitting the string by the dash car and getting the element at position 0 would be cleaner IMO.

Comment: is there any possibility of other schema

Comment: Font files could be named anything, so you would have to ensure they are named this way for this answer to work.

Comment: if that's the case how to get the font family and font style from them

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean keeping just the first part of the string, before the dash ?

If so, look at [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) docs, it will do exactly what you want.

No code example for obvious reasons, it's a one-liner that will get you used to the split method.

Comment: yes, it is possible if the only font name is provided in the font file, is it possible do in another way

Comment: if the font file with different name how to get the font family and font style from them